# Custom UICollectionView paging transition

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, core-animation

I know that I can do custom transitions between view controllers but I'm not sure that applies here. I have a collection view with paging enabled. When swiping/paging I want to do a custom transition instead of just sliding across. Is this possible and how would I get started?

Comment: Custom transition? Cou[d you give an example?

Comment: Ok. Just say I wanted to implement my own page turn animation (like the iBook's app) but wanted to us it to transition between collection view 'pages'.

Comment: Oh, you have a horizontally scrolling collection view?

Comment: Yes, sorry. A horizontally scrolling collection view with paging enabled. Rather than just swipe with the paging I'd like to do a custom transition.

Comment: Interesting! Let me think about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research this doesn't seem possible. The only solution would be displaying a collection view in a `UIViewController` and using a custom view controller animation on pan to create a new instance of that view controller with the collection view. Clearly not ideal but the only thing I could come up with.